# delete by ID on a select axios error 400 reactJS

Tags: reactjs, button, axios

Hi guys i have a problem with my button delete, i try to delete a value by id, i used a function .find to retrieve an Id, my get request and post request work well and i test my delete Route with postman and its work as well. i tried some options without success and now im blocked.
Sorry if my post its not clear its my firstime on stackoverflow

```
 import axios from 'axios';
 import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

  const Hazard = () => {
    const [hazardName, setHazardName] = useState('');
    const [hazardList, setHazardList] = useState([]);

    const handleChangeHazard = (event) => {
      setHazardName(event.target.value);
   };

    useEffect(() => {
      const urlHazard = 'http://localhost:8000/hazards';
     axios.get(urlHazard).then((response) => {
       setHazardList(response.data);
     });
    }, []);

    const handleAddHazard = (event) => {
     event.preventDefault();
      const postUrl = 'http://localhost:8000/hazards/add';
     axios
       .post(
       postUrl,
      {
        hazardName,
      },
      {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       },
     }
   )
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
       window.location.reload();
     })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
   };

  const deleteHazard = (id) => {
   const urlDelete = `http://localhost:8000/hazards/${id}`;
   const removeId = hazardList.find((list) => list._id !== hazardList._id);
   console.log(removeId);
  axios
    .delete(urlDelete)
    .then((response) => {
    setHazardList(removeId).then(response.data);
  })
  .catch((error) => console.error(error));
};

return (
  <div className="input-select">
    <h3 className="hazard-title">Aléas</h3>
    <form className="form-hazard">
      <div className="form-hazard-input">
        <select
          onChange={handleChangeHazard}
          name="Aléas"
          className="aleas-select"
          value={hazardName}
       >
        {hazardList.map((val) => (
          <option key={val._id}>{val.hazardName}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
      <input
        className="add-hazard"
        type="text"
        name="text"
        value={hazardName}
        onChange={handleChangeHazard}
      />
      <button
        className="post-hazard"
        type="submit"
        onClick={handleAddHazard}
      >
        Ajouter
      </button>
      <button
        className="delete-hazard"
        type="button"
        onClick={deleteHazard}
      >
        Supprimer
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
);
};

export default Hazard;
```

Comment: in deleteharzad function, you did not use removeId, and id would be event. You can not take it as a parameter for axios.

Comment: what do you mean by id would be an event ? i need to target the value ? and put an onChange on my button ? on my console.log of RemoveId i have an object like this {_id: "605b57bfaebad11a0475e426", hazardName: "Bureau", __v: 0}
hazardName: "Bureau"
__v: 0
_id: "605b57bfaebad11a0475e426"
__proto__ with an id on my browser when i inspect the console but this one never changed its always the same when i change the value with my select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found my error so i give you the solution for the people who would have the same problem
first i use a method .find in my const deleteHazard to retrieve the id :

```
const deleteHazard = () => {
  const removeId = hazardList.find((item) => item.hazardName === hazardName);
  const urlDelete = `http://localhost:8000/hazards/${removeId._id}`;
  axios.delete(urlDelete).then((response) => response.data);
  .catch((error) => console.error(error));
};
```

and after i used the const removeId._id in the url you can use the console.log to check your code. if you have an error like [Object%20object] or [Object, object] its because you dont retrieve the id of the object in my case its removeId that why i took my const removeId with _id in the url. Now i can delete by id without issue.